# Laravel cache is creating issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-cache

So we have an application in which we are using laravel and MySQL and we are facing laravel cache issues. For example, suppose if a user submits a form and we redirect back to the page with some value(flash session or any other data) then laravel is redirecting back to a cached page. If we reload the page then it shows the passed values, anything we do whether it is an update, insert or delete we have to reload it manually even though we redirect or reload the pages by code.
I don't know but I have tried to disable laravel cache but it is still not working.
Even i m calling Artisan commands for every request in my middleware:

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear'); 
        Artisan::call('view:clear'); 
        Artisan::call('route:clear');
```

But it's still now working.I m feeling helpless now.
Please help me :-(

Comment: that sounds like the browser is caching

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326962/stop-a-certain-view-from-caching-in-laravel

Comment: Also you can try with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371943/laravel-redirect-with-no-cache-header